# Outside Angular context?

Tags: angularjs

I have following HTML and JS code:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="test">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
  <span>{{result}}</span>
  <br />
  <button ng-click="a()">A</button>
  <button my-button>B</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl2($scope) {
    $scope.result = 'Click Button to change this string';
    $scope.a = function (e) {
        $scope.result = 'A';
    }
    $scope.b = function (e) {
        $scope.result = 'B';
    }
}

var mod = angular.module('test', []);

mod.directive('myButton', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        //change scope.result from here works
        //But not in bind functions
        //scope.result = 'B';
        element.bind('click', scope.b);
    }
});
```

I bind click event to my-button and want to change `$scope.result` when user clicked button B (similar to ng-click:a() on button A). But the view won't update to the new $scope.result. Someone advised me to call `$scope.$apply()` at the bottom of your event handler.but `$scope.$apply` is called when variable will be outside angular context. How can I evaluate that on button "B" click event is outside angular context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

element.bind() is a low-level (jqLite) call that is not tracked by Angular. So you need to help Angular know that a change happened by calling $scope.$apply(); in the element.bind() handler.

Perhaps do:

```
element.bind('click', function () {
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.b();
    });
});
```